# How to put insert Html button in CkEditor , ClassicEditor build

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor5

I'm pretty new in Vue.js  , and I'm trying to fix the source code. I have the following :

```
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
 data() {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorConfig: {},
...

 <ckeditor
                  :editor="editor"
                  :config="editorConfig"
                  v-model="service.intro_unlocalized.KK"
                ></ckeditor>
```

And it shows as standard [editor](https://prnt.sc/105dqna)
And I don't know how to add a `insert html` button. I was trying to install and put `HtmlEmbeed` plugin but it showed an `error of dublication  of modules`. So I'm stuck now.
Plesae help

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the documentation page https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html-embed.html

To add a custom plugin is quite easy, make sure you already install the plugin

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-embed
```

Then, modify editorConfig: {}

```
 editorConfig: {plugins: [ HtmlEmbed], toolbar: {
                    items: [ 'htmlEmbed', ... ]}},
```

Comment: I have read a doc but when i import HtmlEmbed , I have an error ```CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules```

Comment: can you post your entire ckeditor configuration?

Comment: It is not my code ,but I can see in ``main.js`` file ```import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue";``` and ```Vue.use(CKEditor);``` 
No any general setting are available. Only separately in components as I have described above

Comment: how about if you only set the toolbar and add 'htmlEmbed' without importing the plugin. I wondering its already imported by CKEditor by default

Comment: I have tried , but nothing I have checked the full plugins which are included into ClassicEditor build and they are: https://prnt.sc/10651j3. I have checked through this command ```ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins.map((plugin) =>
      console.log(plugin.pluginName)
    );```